# Why unity says that there are compiler errors in my code?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, I started learning unity and try to create a simple playercontroller script, it looks good, and I was sure it was going to work, but unity says that "All compilers errors have to be fixed before you enter the playmode", so I ask you to help me to find these compilers errors because I can see none. Thank you in advance:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(PlayerPhysics))]
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

// Player handling
public float speed = 8;
public float acceleration = 12;

private float currentSpeed;
private float targetSpeed;
private Vector2 amountToMove;

private PlayerPhysics playerPhysics;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    playerPhysics = GetComponent<PlayerPhysics>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    targetSpeed = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * speed;
    currentSpeed = IncrementTowards(currentSpeed, targetSpeed, acceleration);
    amountToMove = new Vector2(currentSpeed, 0);
    playerPhysics.Move(amountToMove * time.deltaTime);
}

private float IncrementTowards(float n, float target, float a)
{
    if (n == target)
    {
        return n;
    }
    else
    {
        float dir = Mathf.Sign(target - n);
        n+= a * Time.deltaTime * dir;
        return (dir == Mathf.Sign(target-n))? n: target;
    }
}
}
```

And there is PlayerPhysics script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerPhysics : MonoBehaviour
{
public void Move(Vector2 moveAmount)
{
transform.Translate(moveAmount);
}
}
```

Comment: *I ask you to help me to find these compilers errors because I can see none.* and I ask you to please attach the compile Errors you see in the Unity Console.

Comment: `Why unity says that there are compiler errors in my code?` .. probably because .. there are!

Comment: You have a simple typo: `playerPhysics.Move(amountToMove * time.deltaTime);` it is `Time.deltaTime` with capital `T`.. voting bro close this as typo-based

Answer (score -1):

Fix Here

playerPhysics.Move(amountToMove * time.deltaTime);

time.deltaTime -> Time.deltaTime

```
void Update()
{
    targetSpeed = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * speed;
    currentSpeed = IncrementTowards(currentSpeed, targetSpeed, acceleration);
    amountToMove = new Vector2(currentSpeed, 0);
    playerPhysics.Move(amountToMove * time.deltaTime);
}
```

:)

Comment: Of course, thats my kind of mistake, thanks :)

Comment: Pure typo-based questions are off-topic on StackOverlow and [should not be answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo) ;)